# how to define null as integer value on mysql server?

Tags: mysql, null, integer

I need to allow saving null as integer value on mysql server, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you please reword the question? As it is now, it makes little sense...

Comment: i think you define the fields as not null, you need to declare it as accept null

Comment: well if i sent a value as null or '' it should be automatically convert to zero while inserting or updating to the table on mysql server.
I did this before, yet I completely forgot how.

Comment: This is the error that I'm having while trying to insert nothing as integer
`Incorrect integer value: '' for column ..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how:
I hided the line below then restarted the sql server and it worked.

> # Set the SQL mode to strict 
>   sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Note this line is found in my.ini file.

Comment: Please note that this loosens integrity checks for the entire server and may affect other apps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your question is about the "Incorrect integer value" error message...

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `foo` (
    ->  `foo_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->  `foo_size` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (foo_size) VALUES ('');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'foo_size' at row 1
```

... that means that your server is running in strict mode (which is actually good). You can disable it:

```
mysql> SET @@session.sql_mode='';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO foo (foo_size) VALUES ('');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'foo_size' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+--------+----------+
| foo_id | foo_size |
+--------+----------+
|      1 |        0 |
+--------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... and your error will be downgraded to warning.

Comment: So, anyway, the warnings still exist? Even the '' can be inserted as 0 in the table, is that correct?

Comment: @zhihong - Sorry, I'm not sure of what your question is :-?

Comment: @Alvaro-I mean: After disable the strict mode, when insert value '' to a integer data type, though '0' is inserted, it still generates the warnings. Because mysql still recognize the '' as an empty string, not a 0 integer value. I want to find a way that can treat the '' as an integer, insert 0 in the table, and have no warning generated. But by now, have no luck.

Comment: @zhihong - All I can say is that it works for me. Code in my answer is copied from a real MySQL session.

Answer (score 1):

Set the field to not null and set its default to zero:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `foo` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Value of `foo` will be zero if you send it NULL.

Comment: no there is a way that changes all null to zero, without having to do it for each table one by one. It works for all tables automatically.

Comment: @zeina, you explicitly said "while inserting or updating to the table" :-?

Comment: yes the null should be converted to zero while doing so automatically to any table.